# BASH: How to correctly return true and false from a function

Tags: bash, function, boolean, return, kill

I have a function in a bash script that I want to return true if a process is running and false if not. The code for my function is:

```sh
    checkProcess() {
        if [ kill -s 0 $(getPid) > /dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        fi 
    }
```

When I use this function it does not seem to work. I use it like so:

```sh
    if [ ! checkProcess ]; then
        #do something, like rm file containing PID
    fi
```

However if I just use the below implementation it works fine:

```sh
    if [ ! kill -s 0 $(getPid) > /dev/null 2>&1 ]; then
        #do something, like rm file containing PID
    fi
```

Is there a reason for this? Am I not returning the correct values in my function? Or is it all just wrongly implemented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[` is not syntax; it is a command. It is commonly used with `if`, which works based on its return code.

To directly check the return code of a different command, e.g. `kill`, you should remove the `[` and `]` (the last argument to `[`):

```
if kill -s 0 $(getPid) &>/dev/null; then
    # ...
fi
```

Note that `&>` is a Bash extension, equivalent to `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So should I use the [ and ] in  if [ -f $somefile ]; then

Comment: @james02 yes, that would test for the existence of the file with the name `$somefile`, although you should always quote your variables `[ -f "$somefile" ]`.

Comment: Both! See this [article on quotes in bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) for more info on why quoting your variables is a good idea.